# Actually can I compile Orion Context Broker into i686 Architecture?

Tags: c++, 32-bit, fiware-orion

I was looking at available RPM packages and just one version(0.8.1-dev) has with any architecture.

You can compile the Context Broker in a 32-bit architecture? (I686)

I made a test and I think it's not possible to compile and install it without changes into source code.

Above has my install output:

```
[root@localhost fiware-orion]# make install INSTALL_DIR=/usr
./scripts/build/compileInfo.sh --release
27c27
< #define COMPILE_TIME     "Thu Aug 7 09:27:06 BRT 2014"
---
> #define COMPILE_TIME     "nodate"
mkdir -p  BUILD_RELEASE || true
cd BUILD_RELEASE && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DBUILD_ARCH=i686 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE set to RELEASE
Compiling in system Linux-2.6.32-431.el6.i686
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: 'RELEASE'
cmake: RELEASE compilation
Building for i686
cmake: OK
contextBroker: Other DISTRO: 'CentOS_6.5'
proxyCoap: Other DISTRO: 'CentOS_6.5'
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE
cd BUILD_RELEASE && make -j1
make[1]: Entrando no diretório `/tmp/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
make[2]: Entrando no diretório `/tmp/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
make[3]: Entrando no diretório `/tmp/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
make[3]: Saindo do diretório `/tmp/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
[0%] Built target lm
make[3]: Entrando no diretório `/tmp/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
make[3]: Saindo do diretório `/tmp/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
make[3]: Entrando no diretório `/tmp/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
[0%] Building CXX object src/lib/parseArgs/CMakeFiles/pa.dir/paLimitCheck.cpp.o
cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
/tmp/fiware-orion/src/lib/parseArgs/paLimitCheck.cpp: In function ‘int limits(PaiArgument*, PaiArgument*)’:
/tmp/fiware-orion/src/lib/parseArgs/paLimitCheck.cpp:175: error: format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int64_t’
/tmp/fiware-orion/src/lib/parseArgs/paLimitCheck.cpp:175: error: format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int64_t’
/tmp/fiware-orion/src/lib/parseArgs/paLimitCheck.cpp:180: error: format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int64_t’
/tmp/fiware-orion/src/lib/parseArgs/paLimitCheck.cpp:180: error: format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 5 has type ‘int64_t’
(...)
make[3]: Saindo do diretório `/tmp/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
make[2]: ** [src/lib/parseArgs/CMakeFiles/pa.dir/all] Erro 2
make[2]: Saindo do diretório `/tmp/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
make[1]: ** [all] Erro 2
make[1]: Saindo do diretório `/tmp/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
make: ** [release] Erro 2
```

PS: Sorry for OS language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'm afraid you'd have to modify the source code in order to compile the broker in a 32 bit environment. Never really thought about it ...

It shouldn't be too hard to modify the code to be able to compile in 32 bit also, but we'd need a good reason to invest time on a thing like that.
You can always send a request about it on github (you know where it is :-)).

Comment: There is an old "mock32" target in the makefile (see https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/develop/makefile#L254)... Maybe it could help, although we have used it in a long time.

Comment: To add new issues (@LeonanCarvalho know where it is but probably not other readers ;) use: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/new

Comment: I'm not sure if it's necessary to create a request to that.
Its very interesting to use OCB into a dedicated server, but I'm in front of a case study to use it on systems with a lower resources profile( and low power consumption) like flash servers and mobile devices. But 32bits or 64bits is a hardware limitation that may be overcome.
It's a very special case.